# Prestashop submenu active

Tags: prestashop, submenu

I do so that when I click on the main category (collection) the submenu remains active while if I click on another link as contacts submenu disappears, honestly I would not know how to go about this I ask your help thanks

thank you all for your help

```js
// init Super Fish Menu for 767px+ resolution
function desktopInit()
{
 mCategoryGrover.off();
 mCategoryGrover.removeClass('active');
 $('.sf-menu > li > ul').removeClass('menu-mobile').parent().find('.menu-mobile-grover').remove();
 $('.sf-menu').removeAttr('style');
 categoryMenu.superfish('init');
 //add class for width define
 $('.sf-menu > li > ul').addClass('submenu-container clearfix'); 
  // loop through each sublist under each top list item
    $('.sf-menu > li > ul').each(function(){
        i = 0;
        //add classes for clearing
        $(this).each(function(){ 
            if ($(this).attr('id') != "category-thumbnail"){
                i++;
                if(i % 2 == 1)
                    $(this).addClass('first-in-line-xs');
                else if (i % 5 == 1)
                    $(this).addClass('first-in-line-lg');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```html
ul class="sf-menu clearfix menu-content sf-js-enabled sf-arrows">
   <li><a href="/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/" title="Biography">Biography</a></li>
<li class="sfHoverForce"><a href="/index.php?id_category=49&amp;controller=category&amp;id_lang=1" title="Collection" class="sf-with-ul">Collection</a><ul class="submenu-container clearfix first-in-line-xs" style="display: none;">
<li><a href="/index.php?id_category=63&amp;controller=category&amp;id_lang=1" title="Consolle">Consolle</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="web.com/index.php?id_category=66&amp;controller=category&amp;id_lang=1" title="Cabinetes">Cabinetes</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?id_category=64&amp;controller=category&amp;id_lang=1" title="Bookstores Screens">Bookstores Screens</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?id_category=50&amp;controller=category&amp;id_lang=1" title="Tables">Tables</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?id_category=55&amp;controller=category&amp;id_lang=1" title="Seating">Seating</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?id_category=59&amp;controller=category&amp;id_lang=1" title="LIGHTING ">LIGHTING </a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?id_category=65&amp;controller=category&amp;id_lang=1" title="Mirrors">Mirrors</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?id_category=67&amp;controller=category&amp;id_lang=1" title="Accessories">Accessories</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: The first thing I've noticed is that you're missing the opening "<" from the ul tag. I'm guessing it's a copy-paste gone wrong?

Comment: it is an exact copy paste went wrong, what I need is that when I make the collection click on the submenu remains active, the code is not complete if I can but I do not know how I would like to enclose the entire file. sorry for my bad English